# Matlab: Error in solving implicit equation using fzero

Tags: matlab, optimization, implicit, equation

Equation is:

[image]

where, `a` and `b` are constants and both equal to `0.0130`

This is the code I am using:

```
% Solving the equation for zero.
f = @(theta) ((a+b).*theta)./((theta.^2)-(a.*b)) - tan(theta);  % Notice the dots (.)

% Now plot it to get an idea of where the zeros are.
theta = 0:1:100;
for i=1:length(theta)
    hold on
    plot(theta(i),f(theta(i)),'-o')  % Look for the zeros
end

% Now find the roots.
cnt = 1;
for ii = [0,2,50]  % This vector has the guesses.
    rt(cnt) = fzero(f,ii); % Pass each guess to FZERO.
    cnt = cnt + 1;
end
```

This is the error I get:

```
??? Operands to the || and && operators must be convertible to
logical scalar values.

Error in ==> fzero at 323
    elseif ~isfinite(fx) || ~isreal(fx)

Error in ==> HW4 at 52
    rt(cnt) = fzero(f,ii); % Pass each guess to FZERO.
```

I would like to get the first solution of \theta. Thanks.

Comment: This code works for me with no errors (I wrote the value 0.0130 instead of a and b). Check that you're not using some other variable name in your code, or not clearing some variables...

Comment: Thanks, I found the problem. I had defined `a` and `b` as vector (for uncertainty purpose) and that was causing the problem.

Comment: I copied my comment as an answer to make this question answered...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works for me with no errors (I wrote the value 0.0130 instead of a and b). Check that you're not using some other variable name in your code, or not clearing some variables...